# unknown row but constant column

Tags: c++, sorting, matrix

i need to make a function that take an int matrix of known columns  but varies rows which will be used later in sorting and checking if the matrix is row-magic/column magic I know how to do the sorting, and everything else but my issue is setting the end of my loops because they could be either 4/5/6
Note: I am a student so they don't expect me to use sizeof

```
int sort(int A[? ][5]) {
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i = 0; i < ? ; i++) { // the number of rows 

        int min = A[i][0];
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) { //the number of columns 
            temp = A[i][j];
            if (min > temp) {
                int swap = min;
                min = temp;
                temp = swap;

            }
        }
        int swap = A[i + 1][0];
        if (swap < A[i][5]) {
            int swap1 = A[i][5];
            swap = A[i][5];
            swap1 = A[i + 1][0;]

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Heya! try to follow the stack overflow question guidelines and give us a a minimum reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). From what I understand, you can use `.size()` method of a suitable STL container to get the size at runtime.

Comment: @morpheus i am really sorry this is my first post, and I did make an edit to mention that I am not expected to do .size()/sizeof in my homework at least yet

Comment: @Osama you gotta give us more here. Show us what you did so far. It will be easier for us to find out what to do.

Comment: @Morpheus give me 1 sec i will do the loops and put ? instead of the things I need help with is that fine?

Comment: @Morpheus i think i have alot of mistake

Comment: `A` should be a vector of arrays `std::vector<std::array<int, 5>>`. The array `A` decays to a pointer in the function argument and you can't deduce the number of rows (elements) from a pointer.

Comment: @thomasSablik as in the post at the end as a note I am a student so I am not to use thinks that we didn't take we are currently at pointers so that's why I cant use this sort of answers I am limited to the things I can use first year CS student btw

Comment: STL containers should be the first thing you learn in C++ long before pointers. You wouldn't write such code in C++. To solve your assignment you have to pass the number of rows as additional argument but remember that you're currently not learning C++ but C and these are two different programming languages.

Comment: @thomasSablik unfortunately that not the case for my university most likely because I of where I live considering it as a third world country, and because of the system the university of teaching only basics when it comes to CS because they believe its up to the students to learn and the basics and what they should offer starting with input output to loops to statements to arrays, strings and pointers  that all  i learned .

Comment: @Osama I know about this and this is very sad because you are learning to write legacy code. After you learned that you have to unlearn all of this and learn modern C++ to start a job in programming. I know it's not your fault but it will become your problem later. It's important that you know about it.

Comment: @thomasSablik like in my code my only issue is the number of rows once I get to the number of the row I can set my loops to end  which will help me in ordering my code better, and in as you can see I want to check if the end of the last number of the previous row is greater then the first on of the new row , and I cant fix that until I get the exact number so is there another basic way to get the number of rows ?

Answer (score 1):

The array `A` decays to a pointer when it's passed to the function and a pointer doesn't contain any information about the size. You have to pass the number of rows as additional function argument:

```
int sort(int A[][5], int rows)
```

Comment: XD i was so taken into the array sorting  that I forgot how the question is asked               
write a function that sorts a 2-D array of integers, of varying number of rows
and 5 columns

Comment: thanks alot for the help and your time am really sorry for wasting your time